# How can I read an CSS variable in :root from an Angular component?

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I tried to do it, like this:

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.style['--config-use-images'];
```

and

```
document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--config-use-images');
```

Both did not work. The variable is definitely there. I can see it in the dev tools under `:root`. With the first one I get an undefined and the second one an empty string when I log it in the console.

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue('--config-use-images')
```

Or

```
getComputedStyle(this.elementRef.nativeElement).getPropertyValue('--config-use-images')
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked like a charm